# firebase child_added event issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get recently added child node from firebase database at the moment of pushing but not the last child node of database at all.

The problem is that the typical `child_added` event gets the last child anyway even on page loading at first time.

This code will output last child even if at this time no new nodes were added.

```
firebase.database().ref("coupons").limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

This "hack" is working for me now but how to rewrite it in appropriate way?

```
firebase.database().ref().on('child_changed', function() { // listen only when there are some changes in entire db, the key solution for this purpose.
   firebase.database().ref("coupons").limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
});
```

So, why just `child_added` listener works if at this time no new nodes were added?

Comment: This is expected behavior according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) "This event will be triggered *once for each initial child at this location*, and it will be triggered again every time a new child is added..."

Comment: So, my "hack" is legit? :)

Comment: Nope, this "hack" is bugged :(

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend that. The `firebase.database().ref().on()` is going to download the entire database and that is going to be data-intensive for the client. Perhaps use `'value'` instead of `'child_added'` and use a boolean to keep track of the first time it's triggered and ignore this time? I'll see if I can think of something else.

Comment: @JenPerson In this case OP is using `on('child_changed` , so that won't download the entire database.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by assigning a bool var for checking the first time initiation to skip firebase event on page load.

```
var child_added_first = true;
firebase.database().ref("coupons").limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   if (!child_added_first) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
   }
   child_added_first = false;
});
```

Furthermore, 'child_added' is triggered by firebase on the client when I just simply remove some node from my firebase db in console panel. Why?

Seems it's time to look at some other realtime SaaS databases with more friendly api and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, if you have a time node.

```
firebase.database().ref("coupons")
.orderByChild('time').startAt(Date.now())
.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```